# Repeat values based on column with counter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of characters and a number for each

```
| Character | Count |
|-----------|-------|
| Sam       |   2   |
| Jim       |   4   |
| Larry     |   1   |
| Bob       |   2   |
```

Ideally, I would like to list them like this

```
Sam 1
Sam 2
Jim 1
Jim 2
Jim 3
Jim 4
Larry
Bob 1
Bob 2
```

I'd like to do this with a single excel formula that I can run straight down.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: does the number count need to be in the same cell, or can it be in an adjacent cell?

Comment: It could be an adjacent cell.

Answer (score 0):

VBA seems easier to me... make a button in the sheet or on the ribbon and then it is just a one click action, not even running down a formula.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know VBA. Know if you have an idea for how to do it I may be able to figure it out. Thanks for the input

Comment: Not sure if I've got time for today, but will send it otherwise tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create the list of names with the increasing numbers based on the number of times exists.
Open a VBA screen, insert a new module and copy/paste the code.
As you mentioned you don't know VBA, be aware that macro's **can not be undone** with Ctrl + Z for example. Once run, the result will be there.

```
Sub repeat_values()

Dim name_count, count, i, j, k As Double

name_count = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To name_count
    count = Range("B" & i).Value '-->times to repeat the name

    For k = 1 To count
        j = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row '--> determines everytime the last row
        Range("D" & j).Offset(1, 0) = Range("A" & i).Value '--> columns for the names, change "D" to the desired column if you wish
        Range("E" & j).Offset(1, 0) = k '--> column for the counting, change the letter "E" if you would like to have it in the same column
    Next k
Next i

End Sub
```

Note: It will always continue from the first new available line in column D, so it will not delete old data. This can be added of course. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image: POC]

Assuming your data is layed out like above, use the following formulas.  Adjust your ranges as required.

The first row of your list is a special case that acts for the seed of your list.

In A1 use:

```
=F1
```

In B1 use

```
1
```

This basically pulls the first entry from your list and assigns the minimum number to it.

In order to build the list and pull the appropriate number of names as you copy your formula down you can use the following formula.  I added the custom error message of "no more characters", but this could be change to blank by using "" instead.

in A2 use the following and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A1,$F$2:$G$5,2,0)=B1,INDEX($F$2:$F$5,MATCH(A1,$F$2:$F$5,0)+1),A1),"no more characters")
```

I used a combination of VLOOKUP and MATCH/INDEX to give you more variety of formulas you could use.

In B2 use the following and copy down.

```
=IF(A2="no more characters","",IF(A1=A2,B1+1,1))
```

If you changed the error message adjust it in this formula to match.